# Windows phone Canvas.Left property after scale

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an image in Canvas;
When scaling my image, its left and top property does not change, but left of the scaled image is actually some other value that i can only get by calculating manually
Is there any way to update my images Cavas.Left?

Comment: Can you post some code and screenshots? The question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
    Canvas.SetLeft(yourImage, *newValue*);
```

or this:

```cs
    yourImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, *newValue*);
```

Comment: My problem was that when i use CompositeTransform.Scale, my images visual size changes thus its acutal left, but Canvas.GetLeft(myImage)
still return value of left property before it is scaled.
I created my own variable that i named 
actualLeft and after every change i calculate it in my code
I just wanted to know if it was possible to update Canvas.Left property so it shows real value after Scale, i searched for quite some time and did not find anything like it so i think the right way  is to manually calculate

Answer (score 0):

You need use Grid control instead of Canvas.